# How can I back from the second fragment to the first fragment using Navigation Component?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

How can I back from the second fragment to the first fragment using Navigation Component?

**navigation_main.xml**

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/firstFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:name="com.test.ttt.FirstFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/secondFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/firstFragment" 
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:name="com.test.ttt.SecondFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second" />

</navigation>
```

**FirstFragment.java**

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Navigation.findNavController(container).navigate(FirstFragmentDirections.actionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment());
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    }

}
```

I want when I press the back button in the second fragment, It must back to the first fragment but currently, When I press the back button in the second fragment it is leaving the app.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are being exited from the app is because while navigating to the second fragment, you are removing the first fragment from your stack. The properties `app:popUpTo` and `app:popUpToInclusive` are typically used when you want to remove some fragments from your backstack while navigating. A simple use case for this would be when navigating from Login/SignUp Fragment to Home/Main Fragment. In this case you would not want the user to be able to press back and go back to login/signup screens. Here is where the two properties would help.

TL;DR - Remove the `app:popUpTo` and `app:popUpToInclusive` properties from your action

Change

```
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment"
        app:destination="@id/secondFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@id/firstFragment" 
        app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
```

to

```
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment"
        app:destination="@id/secondFragment"/>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but when clicking on a back button will not back to the first fragment and it is not exit the app (Nothing Happen)

Comment: @E3219 just to clarify, by back button you mean the actual device back button or do you have a back button in your layout?

Comment: Device button...

Comment: Okay, Your answer is correct, When I click on the back button in the second fragment it will move me to the first fragment and after opening the first fragment it will move me again to the second fragment because there is a command in the first fragment `Navigation.findNavController(container).navigate(FirstFragmentDirections.actionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment());`, So I thought it's not working but it's working well but I can't notice that.

Comment: There is a problem when I back from the second to the first fragment, The first fragment will recreate again, How can I avoid that?

Comment: You can't really avoid that as the default behavior of Navigation Component is to replace fragments when navigating. For one, you can look into when you need to call your logic.